# Sonido personalizado al recibir una Notificacion

Tags: java, android-studio

Hola estoy creando una alarma, y quiero añadirle un Ringtone personalizado
pero al intentar poner el sonido personalizado y ejecutar la app en un celular este  solo da el tono por defecto y no el personalizado, este es mi código

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;


import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;



public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        String message = intent.getStringExtra("todo");

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 /* Request code */, mainIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
        String channelId = "channel-01";
        String channelName = "Alarm Notification";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                    .build();

            mChannel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.cat), audioAttributes);




        }

        Bitmap largicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
                .setContentTitle("Ya es hora dormilon!")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setLargeIcon(largicon)
                //.setBadgeIconType(R.mipmap.ic_notification_round)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.cat))
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(importance)

                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);


        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT


        );

        //mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        //mBuilder.setSound(soundUri, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);



        //vibrate
        long[] v = {500,1000};
        mBuilder.setVibrate(v);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());



    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Max, en lugar de "android.resource://" usa ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE , saludos!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo unico que tienes que realizar es definir el sonido a reproducir en el `NotificationCompat.Builder` mediante el método `setSound()`.

Anteriormente y ahora solo para dispositivos con API <= 26 :

Agrega tu archivo de sonido dentro del directorio /raw ,  suponiendo agregaste un archivo mysound.mp3, esta sería la forma de cargarlo :

```
mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mysound));
```

**Pero ahora para dispositivos con API > 26 , en lugar de `"android.resource://"`  usa `ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE`** de esta forma:

```
mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.mysound))
```

---

Recuerda también que para este sistema operativo debes definir un canal y en este caso agregar:

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mysound);

 AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();

   mChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes); //* Esto configuraría el sonido custom.
```

hay algo importante, **si ya se creo el canal y se definieron sus propiedades, no puedes realizar modificaciones, tendrás que eliminarlo y volver a crearlo**.

Comment: Hum me sigue sondando el audio por defecto

Comment: Ok recuerda que debes definir un canal para la notificación y a este debes definirle el sonido, hay algo importante, si ya se creo el canal no puedes realizar modificaciones @Max

Comment: entonces para que funcione tengo que cambiar la id y el nombre del canal?

Comment: Si, exactamente Max, crearlo desde el inicio con esa propiedad y definiendo ese sonido. Anteriormente tenía apps en las cuales el usuario podría definir el sonido del dispositivo o el uno personalizado, ahora desgraciadamente ya no podemos realizar esto desde android 8.0